# Microphone issue Samsung GS2

Tags: microphone, application-autoupdate

name is Blenderpony

Since half a year now I am stuck with a problem.

My Phones (Samsung GS2) Mic level is ridiculous low. You barely hear anything.
Ofc Some would suggest that the mic might be broken or anything. But its not.

If I do a factory reset. The Mic works how its supposed to. Nice loud and clear. No annying background Noise, nothing.

But the moment I turn on wifi or mobile data. And all the updates from the google play store or samsung with it.. My mic just decides to knock the volume level down to 1% out of of possible 100

There isnt really a setting I can use to get it back up.

The Service menu isn't working because Samsung blocked it in the most recent OS updates.

There arent any apps because the Phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I had same problem with one of my device few months back. What i did i kept reseting my phone to factory level and it use to get fixed for a while. But later on it use to give me same problem. Then i restarted my phone safe mode and tried testing the mic. It was working fine, then i uninstalled all unnecessary app. That fixed my problem. Please give it a try. If that doesn't work for you. Try reinstalling your phone's OS yourself or go to the service center. That will surely fix your problem.